# Loging on a cached page in an ESI component redirects on /_internal/secure/.../none.html

Tags: symfony, varnish, esi

I've just setup varnish and i've done some tests on port 8080 before switching in production.

I've noticed that if i'm on a cached page :

```
/**
 * @Cache(smaxage="10800")
 * @Route("/{_locale}/", name="homepage2", requirements={"_locale" = "en|fr"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return array();
}
```

And I try to login (not using external services, but with normal login) via the component included via an `ESI`

```
    {% render "GamerCertifiedHomeBundle:Home:login" with {}, { 'standalone': true } %}
```

It ends up redirecting me on a page with no style and no head with the url `...:8080/_internal/secure/MyBundleHomeBundle:Home:login/none.html`

[Step1 Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/7ycyf17DOt) / [Step2 Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/wxGNTFVy)

If I go back on the homepage, i'm logged in.

How can I avoid that please ?

EDIT :

- [Apache2.conf](https://gist.github.com/ccfd6c970d42ab94949e)
- [Apache vhost](https://gist.github.com/8458118ed27ce6f86801)
- [Varnish VCL](https://gist.github.com/bba902cfa9f875abbb34)

Comment: Just to be sure - didn't you forget to include `_internal` routing in your `routing.yml`?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure, i've uncommented the _internal route in routing.yml

Comment: What do you use - nginx or apache?

Comment: @thecatontheflat Apache2

Comment: Could you upload your config to somewhere?

Comment: Y sure, i've put the apache2.conf on gist. See my edit on original post.

Comment: And, of course, virtual host config ;)))

Comment: Sure, sorry : https://gist.github.com/8458118ed27ce6f86801

Comment: And the last will - please, attach your varnish config as well.

Comment: Probably, your virtual host should also listen to 8080 port?

Comment: Well, i'm sorry i forgot to update the VCL, varnish listen on the port 80, where the application is (for now).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14918/discussion-between-tristan-and-thecatontheflat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the problem in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14918/discussion-between-tristan-and-thecatontheflat) I found that `_target_path` for security successful redirect is generated in form in the next way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.uri }}" />
```

And since this part is rendered with standalone view - it has specific uri (with `_internal` prefix).

You can avoid this by applying changed logic for your `app.request.uri` injection.

1. Pass it to controller:

   ```
    {% render yourAction with {'uri': app.request.uri}, {'standalone': true} %}
   ```
2. In your controller just pass it to your view

   ```
    public function yourAction ($uri)
    {
        ...
        return array('uri' => $uri);
    }
   ```
3. Use it in your template

   ```
     <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ uri }}" />
   ```

---

Enjoiy! ;)

Comment: My VCL is this following : https://gist.github.com/bba902cfa9f875abbb34 I don't have the forwarded port but i do have the req.http.Auth

Comment: Definitly a thing to remember when working with ESI !! Thanks you